Lodash chaining multiple set throws error in TypeScript
As far as I know, we can chain functions in lodash using chain(). But it seems that when used in typescript, it throws a TypeError.
I have this logic in typescript:
try {
    // an async code here...

    const updatedConfig = chain(config as object)
        .set('key1.attr1.value', a)
        .set('key1.attr2.value', b)
        .set('key2.attr1', {
          subAttr1: c,
          subAttr2: d,
          subAttr3: e,
        })
        .value();
} catch (err) {
    console.log('error', err);
}

But, it seems that it fails at the chaining operation, because it is caught by my catch block Here is the error:
TypeError: lodash_chain__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13___default(...)(...).set is not a function

As far as I know, this should work, but it seems that I am getting an error. I am not sure what caused this one, in my code, I didnt even have an eslint warning. Any help is really appreciated.
